# How to port a Visual Studio project to Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, porting

I have a C# project I created with Visual Studio that contains a form and I want to port it to Unity. I have googled it, but I have only seen the reverse, building a Unity project to a Visual Studio solution for UWP.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think there is no magic to do this. but, what is about your currently code? is it a web site and you need to reuse some part of it in Unity? cause if so, you will need to copy the code by yourself. I don't think any tools will do it for you.

Comment: do you want to have the form in Unity? do you want information on form creation in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

You either have to recreate the form using a GUI framework such as [Unitys built-in](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui) or a third party framework such as [Noesis Engine](http://www.noesisengine.com/) which supports Xaml, data binding and MVVM.

Unity does not support Windows Forms or WPF, so UI-wise this is a near complete rewrite.

To clarify a bit: Unity runs on a limited version of .Net based on Mono. It has a custom compile pipeline separate from Visual Studio and C# projects. Unity compiles to many platforms and takes care of the implementation details for you. This means that Windows-only frameworks such as Windows Forms and WPF can't be used, since they rely on the Windows API. Other code can however be shared, so with a proper presentation layer separation (i.e. MVC or MVVM) much of the code can be shared.